# Link Ruby to crypto library

Tags: ruby, linux

```
ruby -e 'require "digest/md5"'
```

Throws error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any idea how to link Ruby to crypto library?

Trying to run Ruby on Rails on QNAP NAS Server.

Operating system is ARM Linux.

**Edit:**

Tried to make links to libraries using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export RUBYLIB=/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/armv5tel-linux-eabi/digest:$RUBYLIB
```

but i don't know if I'm doing it right.

**Solved**

```
ln -s /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

did the trick.

Comment: Maybe the shared library is not installed. I don't know what kind of packet manager you have on ARM linux, on a debian based you would certainly solve this with a sudo aptitude install libcrypto-dev.

Comment: Shared library is installed.
`find / -name 'libcrypto.so.0.9.8'
/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8`
Using Ipkg package manager.

Comment: @lc2817 Using Ipkg package manager.
Libcrypto library is installed with openssl package.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions provided by running `rvm requirements` solved this for me.